# Validation Error Templates For UserControl

Tags: wpf

I have built an UserControl. I don't like the red border showing around it when validation errors occur. I have a textbox inside my control.

How can I override the validation error style to get rid of the red border in the whole control and just show a red background in the textbox inside my usercontrol?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am using this template that will color the background of the textbox instead of showing just the border.

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true" >
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="MistyRose"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1.0"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                 Self},Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

And all I have to do to your  DocPannel Where the controls are located for example for me inside a DockPanel then i have to set its `Validation.Error` template to nothing this will remove the border.

**For Ex:**

```
    <TextBox >
       <Validation.ErrorTemplate>
         <ControlTemplate>
         </ControlTemplate>
       </Validation.ErrorTemplate>
     </TextBox>
```

Comment: This does not work for me. The behavior demonstrates that the parent window's validation template overrides the user control's text box style. Of course, this leads me to try to create an style for the invalid user control input in the parent window, but I have not yet found any means to modify the text box background provided through the user control.

If you could offer more explanation, that would be great!

Comment: Yes You must be seeing Red border on your user control rather than your textbox. It should be because the parent should also set their `Validation.ErrorTemplate` as we did it for textbox. Suppose for example the Root_LayoutContainer of the user control is grid then set Grid's Validtion.ErrorTemplate you should not see this anymore on you user control.

Comment: Thank you Nivid! I kept getting turned around but eventually got this working. I removed any Validation.HasError styles applied to the user control from the parent (in my case, the grid from the MainWindow.xaml) and wrote the style for the text boxes in the user control file in the user control xaml file (as you demonstrated). This much I understood but what I missed was that I needed to implement IDataErrorInfo in the usercontrol .cs code and validate the dependency properties. I had hoped setting up validation in the parent object xaml and view model would triggered the control's components.

Comment: i dont know if Validation.ErrorTemplate is really usable. If i set there the background then control isnt clicable because it sits on top maybe. I guess trigger is the best way

Answer (score 0):

On the style for your user control:

```
<Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{x:Null}"/>
```

On the style for your textbox:

```
<Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">
                <Border 
                      Name="Border"
                      CornerRadius="5" 
                      Padding="2"
                      BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                      Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                      BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" >
                    <ScrollViewer Margin="0"  x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Border" Value="{DynamicResource ErrorBorderColor}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border" Value="{DynamicResource ErrorBackgroundColor}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
```

Comment: This does not work. Even if I set the BG color without DynamicResource it won't show. Is like the Validation.HasError property is not linked to the UserControl's.

Comment: You need to make sure that the property that you are expecting the error to come from has ValidatesOnDataErrors="true" and ValdidatesOnExceptions="true"