# How to pass validation to a child control of a User Control

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml, mvvm

I have created a user control that consists of a Telerik RadMaskedInput and a Label. The user control is a floating label input something like seen here: 
http://css-tricks.com/float-labels-css/
The problem I am having is that when the control validates, the whole control is getting the red validation border. I need just the RadMaskedInput box border to be red. I've seen several other posts and help requests for the same issue, but I can't seem to get anything to work for me. My control's XAML looks like this:

```
<Grid>
        <Label x:Name="controlLabel" 
               VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
               Padding="5,0,5,0" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
               Background="White" 
               Grid.Row="0" 
               Margin="10,0,0,0" 
               Panel.ZIndex="1" 
               IsHitTestVisible="False" 
               Template="{DynamicResource LabelControlTemplate1}"
               Content="{Binding ElementName=floatingLabelTextBox, Path=LabelContent}"
               FontFamily="{Binding ElementName=floatingLabelTextBox, Path=LabelFontFamily}"
               FontSize="{Binding ElementName=floatingLabelTextBox, Path=LabelFontSize}"
               Foreground="{DynamicResource FloatingLabelTextBox.Label.Foreground}"/>

        <telerik:RadMaskedTextInput x:Name="controlMaskedTextBox" 
                                    Mask="" 
                                    TextMode="PlainText" 
                                    FontWeight="Normal" 
                                    BorderBrush="{DynamicResource FloatingLabelTextBox.BorderBrush}" 
                                    BorderThickness="1" 
                                    SelectionOnFocus="SelectAll" 
                                    IsClearButtonVisible="False"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" 
                                    VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
                                    Value="{Binding TextBoxText,
                                                   Mode=TwoWay,
                                                   UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus,
                                                   ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,
                                                   ValidatesOnExceptions=True,
                                                   NotifyOnValidationError=True}"
                                    GotFocus="TextBox_GotFocus" 
                                    LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus" 
                                    Template="{DynamicResource RadMaskedTextInputControlTemplate1}"/>
</Grid>
```

The RadMaskedTextInput's control template looks like this:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="RadMaskedTextInputControlTemplate1" TargetType="{x:Type telerik:RadMaskedTextInput}">
                <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="True" UseLayoutRounding="True">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="ClearButton"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="ReadOnly">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="GridContainer">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <SolidColorBrush Color="#5EC9C9C9"/>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <!--<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledVisual">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>-->
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="DisplayText">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF8D8D8D"/>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="Content">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF8D8D8D"/>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="DisplayTextContent">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <!--<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusedVisual">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>-->
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="NotFocused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="DisplayTextContent">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="EditorSite">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <SolidColorBrush Color="Transparent"/>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ContentStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="NotEmpty"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Empty">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="DisplayTextContent"/>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="EmptyContent">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Border x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <Grid x:Name="GridContainer">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <MaskedInput:PreviewInputTextBox x:Name="EditorSite" AcceptsReturn="{TemplateBinding AcceptsReturn}" Cursor="{TemplateBinding Cursor}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}" IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsEnabled}" MaskedInputControl="{x:Null}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Style="{TemplateBinding TextBoxStyle}" TabIndex="{TemplateBinding TabIndex}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                                <MaskedInput:PreviewInputTextBox.TextAlignment>
                                    <Binding Path="HorizontalContentAlignment" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}">
                                        <Binding.Converter>
                                            <MaskedInput:HorizontalContentAlignmentToTextAlignmentConverter/>
                                        </Binding.Converter>
                                    </Binding>
                                </MaskedInput:PreviewInputTextBox.TextAlignment>
                            </MaskedInput:PreviewInputTextBox>
                            <Border x:Name="DisplayTextContent" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="0" IsHitTestVisible="False" Visibility="Collapsed">
                                <MaskedInput:PreviewInputTextBox x:Name="DisplayText" Cursor="{TemplateBinding Cursor}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" IsTabStop="False" IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}" IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsEnabled}" MaskedInputControl="{x:Null}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Style="{TemplateBinding TextBoxStyle}" Text="{Binding Text, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                                    <MaskedInput:PreviewInputTextBox.TextAlignment>
                                        <Binding Path="HorizontalContentAlignment" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}">
                                            <Binding.Converter>
                                                <MaskedInput:HorizontalContentAlignmentToTextAlignmentConverter/>
                                            </Binding.Converter>
                                        </Binding>
                                    </MaskedInput:PreviewInputTextBox.TextAlignment>
                                </MaskedInput:PreviewInputTextBox>
                            </Border>
                            <Border x:Name="EmptyContent" IsHitTestVisible="False" Padding="5,0,0,0" Visibility="Collapsed">
                                <ContentControl x:Name="Content" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding EmptyContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding EmptyContent}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontStyle="Italic" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsTabStop="False" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                            </Border>
                            <telerik:RadButton x:Name="ClearButton" Grid.Column="1" Command="{TemplateBinding ClearCommand}" IsTabStop="False" InnerCornerRadius="3" Opacity="0" Style="{TemplateBinding ClearButtonStyle}">
                                <telerik:RadButton.Visibility>
                                    <Binding Path="IsClearButtonVisible" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}">
                                        <Binding.Converter>
                                            <telerik:BooleanToVisibilityConverter/>
                                        </Binding.Converter>
                                    </Binding>
                                </telerik:RadButton.Visibility>
                            </telerik:RadButton>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <!--<Border x:Name="FocusedVisual" BorderBrush="#FFFFC92B" BorderThickness="1" Background="{x:Null}" CornerRadius="5" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                <Border x:Name="DisabledVisual" BorderBrush="#FFD9D9D9" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="3" Visibility="Collapsed"/>-->
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFD9D9D9"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

The dependency property and dp callback in the code behind:

```
public String TextBoxText
        {
            get
            {
                return (String)GetValue(TextBoxTextProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(TextBoxTextProperty, value);
            }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for TextBoxText.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextBoxTextProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("TextBoxText", typeof(String), typeof(FloatingLabelTextBox), new PropertyMetadata() { PropertyChangedCallback = UpdateTextBoxText });

        private static void UpdateTextBoxText(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            FloatingLabelTextBox control = d as FloatingLabelTextBox;

            if (control != null && e.NewValue != null)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.NewValue as string))
                {
                    control.FloatLabel();
                }
                else
                {
                    control.DockLabel();
                }
            }
        }
```

And finally, my code for calling/using the control:

```
<controls:FloatingLabelTextBox LabelContent="Batch #"
                                       TextBoxText="{Binding BatchNumber.StringValue,
                                       Mode=TwoWay,
                                       UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus,
                                       ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,
                                       ValidatesOnExceptions=True,
                                       NotifyOnValidationError=True,
                                       Converter={StaticResource stringToInt}}"
                                       Validation.ErrorTemplate="{x:Null}"
                                       LabelForeground="{DynamicResource FloatingLabelTextBox.Label.Foreground}"
                                       LabelFontSize="12"
                                       TextBoxWidth="150"
                                       TextBoxHeight="30"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                       Grid.Row="1"
                                       IsEnabled="{Binding BatchNumber.IsReadOnly, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource inverseBool}}" />
```

Note that I am using the MVVM pattern. I have modeled my code from here: [Validation Error Templates For UserControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808986/validation-error-templates-for-usercontrol)  but I'm not seeing expected results. I'm not seeing any validation border at all.

I've been on this issue way too long. Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you looked at the `Telerik` site they have pretty good documented examples

Comment: Yes I have MethodMan. I think this is outside of the realm of Telerik. What I mean is that I have replaced the Telerik control with a simple Text Box and have the same issue. In other words, the child being a Telerik control that I want validated is kinda a moot point. Thanks for your suggestion though.

Comment: Just to be sure there was nothing inside the Telerik control template interfering with the border color change, I changed the border color to Red in the other (IsEnabled = false) trigger and it changed perfectly. Just not changing with validation errors.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get any good answers to solve this problem. I tried everything I could possibly think of. I feel confident this is possible, but having a deadline, I needed to get something going. My solution was to rework the control so that I was extending the base control. In this case, I extended the Telerik RadMaskedTextInput control and overrode the control template, added the floating label to the template, and used a series of triggers to achieve what I needed. This allowed me to use the native validation for the Telerik control so nothing had to be passed. For my case, this is probably a better solution than creating a user control. In the case that a more complex control would be needed, I have no good suggestions on how to make this work and would love to see a comment or suggestions to simply satisfy my curiosity. Thanks to MethodMan for taking the time to respond.